# Put html link in edittext android

Tags: android

I want to put `<a href="google.com" target="_blank">google</a>` in edittext and when I click on this text I want to open webview. How can I do that?

Comment: use this method...setAutoLinkMask() Automatically Finds url and email id and make it clickable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your html in a string@

```
<string url="link">&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">Google&lt;/a></string>
```

set `String to editText`@

```
youredittext.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.url)));
```

For click, set `LinkMovementMethod` with necessary action@

```
youredittext.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code:

```
yourEditText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
EditText et = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et);
et.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">Google</a> "));
et.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want that in an EditText??

What if you just use a button with the text "Google", and use it's onclick to call a method in your xml like:

```
android:onClick="openGoogleWebview"
```

and then add in your code

```
public void openGoogleWebview()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoogleWebviewActivity.class)
}
```