# How to add Custom Text instead of URL in Deeplink message

Tags: android, ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm integrating Firebase to support Deeplink feature in app. I have seen in one of screen-example suggested(PFA) [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/) that we can add our own custom text instead of display Deep link URL.

[image]

I have tried to update but that did not help. How to do that, Any suggestion?

Comment: It looks like they are just creating HTML with the link in an anchor tag.

Comment: This looks same. But I have no idea how to do in Deep Link SMS Text message. I just wanted to display some Hyperlinked text instead if Full URL. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't think its an SMS in this example, as far as I know SMS's are not formatted by HTML, so it wouldn't be possible to do it.

Comment: I agree with @riggaroo, I don't think the screenshot is an SMS message because the app enables the user to send location, voice, and image. That is just another messaging app. [original screenshot here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/images/user-to-user.png)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using a `UITextView` for when the user enters text (in iOS). Here is how to accomplish that in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: Any) {
        let range = textView.selectedRange
        let linkString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
        linkString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: textField.text ?? "", range: range)
        textView.attributedText = linkString
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        return false
    }
}
```

In Android, I found a couple of SO answers that seem to handle the topic well:

[Make a hyperlink textview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290651/make-a-hyperlink-textview-in-android)

From user370305:

> Try this, and let me know what happen..
>
> ```
> TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
> textView.setClickable(true);
> textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
> String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
> textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
> ```

[Put html link in edittext android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020990/put-html-link-in-edittext-android)

From RobinHood:

> Put your html in a string@
>
> ```
> <string url="link">&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">Google&lt;/a></string>
> ```
>
> set String to editText@
>
> ```
> youredittext.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.url)));
> ```
>
> For click, set LinkMovementMethod with necessary action@
>
> ```
> youredittext.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
> ```

If you are trying to accomplish this in HTML, then use an anchor (`a`) tag:

```html
<p>Click on this <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: Caleb, I'm not talking to just create Hyperlink. How we can convert Deep link to Hyperlink Text and can send it inform of SMS. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Shubh Sorry. I am a little confused as to what you want. Can you expound on that a little more?

Comment: In Deep Link SMS Text, I want to replace Deep Link URL with Hyperlink Small-Text.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing in one of my apps. Please follow below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    tools:context="tdsolutions.com.clickabletext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World this text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Pass your Textview to below method(setClickableText):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
  setClickableText(text);
}

private void setClickableText(TextView textView) {
        String text = "this"; // the text you want to mark as a link

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(textView.getText());// full text
        final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#91ca46"));//link text color

        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                //What ever the code you want when click on text goes here
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"you clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };

        int start = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(text);
        int length = start + text.length();

        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, length, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        ss.setSpan(fcs, start, length, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(ss);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Or you can use below code:

Add the text view as below, change whatever the attributes as you wish.

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textColorLink="#00f"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then add below code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Spanned result;
String html = "Hi sweetheart go to <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">this</a> link";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    result = Html.fromHtml(html ,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
} else {
    result = Html.fromHtml(html);
}
textView.setText(result);
textView. setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

please make sure when you add links replace them with html tags as I did in the example `String html = "Hi sweetheart go to <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">this</a> link";`

Comment: This is not the case @TdSoft. I'm asking if we can display Hyperlinked Text instead of showing Deeplink URL. Any Clue ?

Comment: But this will not work if you do text message. It consider HTML tag as plain text & so does not create Hyperlinked text.